# How to generate java code from xsd using jaxb and not allowing the user to use the xml attribute

Tags: jaxb

I'm using JAXB to generate java code from xsd.

I want to generate attribute (Java code) that cannot be used in the xml.

For example:

```
<xs:complexType name="Button">
   <xs:attribute type="xs:string"
                 name="ribbonGroup">
</xs:complexType>
```

I want to see the getter and setter of the attribute ribbonGroup in the Button java class, but I don't want to let the user the option to see this attribute in the xml.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see the getter and setter of
>   the attribute ribbonGroup in the
>   Button java class,

You want to have the get/set method generated for ribbonGroup.  This means you should not use="prohibited" to prevent the generation by XJC.

> but I don't want to let the user the
>   option to see this attribute in the
>   xml.

Am I correct that you mean you don't want the ribbonGroup property to be loaded when reading XML, or saved when writing to XML?  If so, the @XmlTransient annotation is used to prevent a field/property from being marshaled to XML.

Ultimately I believe you want the JAXB XJC tool to generate this annotation?  Is this correct?

Comment: mmm, I want that the user that write the XML occurding to the XSD, won't be able to use the "ribbonGroup" attribute.

Comment: But, I want that the JAXB that generate java code from the XSD will generate the getters and setters to the Button class, cause I want to use it in my code.

Comment: JAXB will generate the get/set for ribbonGroup.  If the property is the marked @XmlTransient it will still exist but will not be populated during an unmarshal or produce an XML attribute when marshalling.

Comment: Will the user that writing the XML from the XDS see this attribute?

Comment: There is a propery called: use="prohibited", this will now allow the user to use the ribbonGroup attribute but the JAXB doesn't generate this attribute (getter and setter) to the Button Class. Can I make the JAXB to generate this attribute althought the use="prohibited" is used?

Comment: this will now allow = this will not allow

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you confirm I have the correct understanding of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set the value of it, when the value of XML is null or empty; it won't create a tag.

and I think Jaxb is not creating a complexType setter. I create my self in my project